# php foreach loop on mysql data from 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have two tables, both with only one column.

```
Table 1:  Merchants
Column:  merchant  (20 entries)

Table 2:  Categories
Column: category  (600 entries)
```

I'm trying to write a for each loop to select all entries within these two tables and list all possible combinations in this format.  For example..

```
merchant1 category1
merchant1 category2
merchant1 category3... all the way to end of categories
merchant2 category1
merchant2 category2
merchant2 category3...all the way to end of categories
etc...
```

Should I use one mysql command to select the data, then use a for each loop?...  or should I run 2 mysql commands and use a nested for each loop on multiple arrays?

Comment: Take cross product of the tables using full outer join

Comment: Could you show me a code example?

Comment: Sorry this isn't super constructive but I'd say "6 of one and half a dozen of the other".

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT `Merchants`.`merchant`, `Categories`.`category`
FROM `Merchants`
JOIN `Categories`;
```

Then do a foreach on the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.(put the star sign), table2.(put the star sign)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

use outer join,

```
SELECT * FROM Merchants, Categories    //Number of Records:20 X 600
```